# How to process the results of a compute operation? (arrow::compute::ValueCounts)

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of different words in a column (`arrow::ChunkedArray`) of `arrow::Type::String`.

I know that `compute::ValueCounts` returns a dictionary `{"values":,"counts"}` (see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html#array-wise-vector-functions), but I can't get the values of this dictionary.

This is what I've got so far, but there is no `operator[]` for `DictionaryScalar`. And, in general, I'm not sure if this is the right way to process the results of `arrow::compute::ValueCounts`.

```cpp
auto count = arrow::compute::ValueCounts(column);
auto countSharedPointer = *count;
auto &countArray = *countSharedPointer;

for (auto i=0; i < countArray.length(); i++){
    auto columnCountResult = countArray.GetScalar(i);
    auto columnCountSharedPointer = *columnCountResult;
    auto columnDictionaryScalar = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::DictionaryScalar>(columnCountSharedPointer);
    // ???
    std::cout << "Word: " << (*columnDictionaryScalar)["values"] << " appears " << (*columnDictionaryScalar)["counts"] << " times.\n";
}
```

Also, I find Apache-Arrow very fast and powerful in c++, but I've struggled to get anything working. Is there a cookbook or a list of examples you can recommend?